# SQL query limited records

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve second 10 records data from database table,
I wrote this query that is not valid for my required records.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * from [upload_news]
```

Comment: Use LIMIT instead of TOP

Comment: There is no TOP in mysql , you have to use LIMIT 10 in your sql. better you learn some sql queries from http://www.w3schools.com/sql

Comment: Is the result set somehow ordered because without you will need some function or some external code I'm afraid.

Comment: @Dexture, SO has whole pages devoted to w3schools http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: LOL :) i never see that post , i am not here recommending OP to just find your answer  from this site. i say him  he must know ABC of mysql. when i was learning ABC of mysql it help me . If you know any site  that help the OP to  learn the ABC of mysql guide him in a good way which i did.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple.....Query end add ->LIMIT 10,10 First 10 define start position and second 10 start to how many record display position so.....**

SELECT * FROM [upload_news] LIMIT 10,10;